# Can't Perform Forward Resolution via Secondary Nameserver to Delegated Zone

Tags: linux, debian, dns, domain, bind

My organization's domain name is **example.com**. The organization's nameservers are named **ns1.example.com** and **ns2.example.com**.

I am the administrator for subdomain **project.example.com**. Our IP address space is **10.0.0.0/22 (10.0.0.0 - 10.0.3.255)**.

I have one primary nameserver and one secondary nameserver (**ns1.project.example.com (10.0.0.2)** and **ns2.project.example.com (10.0.1.2)**, respectively).

These nameservers are Bind 9.10.3 running under Debian 9.5.

I have configured these zones (for which I am either authoritative or I delegate authority:

- project.example.com
- 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa
- 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa
- 2.0.10.in-addr.arpa
- 3.0.10.in-addr.arpa

My organization's nameservers forward (not delegate) queries within the **project.example.com** namespace to my nameservers.

For queries of names I am not authoritative for, do not delegate, do not forward, and do not have cached, I use "Forward Only" mode to forward the query to **ns1.example.com** / **ns2.example.com**.

I have split out a portion of my namespace into sub-domain **sub.project.example.com**. The IP address space for this sub-domain is **10.0.3.0/24**.

There is only one nameserver for **sub.project.example.com**. Its hostname is **ns1.sub.project.example.com (10.0.3.2)**.

This nameserver is Bind 9.9.4 running under CentOS 7.3.

For forward lookups within **sub.project.example.com**, I delegate to **ns1.sub.project.example.com (10.0.3.2)**. I do have the required glue record in place.

For reverse lookups within **3.0.10.in-addr.arpa**, I forward (not delegate) to **ns1.sub.project.example.com (10.0.3.2)**. I cannot delegate since I do not control **0.10.in-addr.arpa**.

### The Problem

There's one particular case where things are not working. This case occurs when I shut down my primary nameserver to test the **secondary** nameserver.

Suppose I open a command prompt on my Windows desktop machine, which is **my-host.example.com**. I cannot query for **host-1.sub.project.example.com**. The request times out.

When I run tcpdump on the secondary nameserver **ns2.project.example.com** **(10.0.1.2)**, I see the query coming in from **ns1.example.com**. However, rather than delegating it to **ns1.sub.project.example.com**, it forwards it back to **ns1.example.com**.

To re-phrase the opening paragraph of this section, the query succeeds if my **primary** nameserver **ns1.project.example.com (10.0.0.2)** is running. If the primary nameserver is down and the secondary nameserver **ns2.project.example.com (10.0.1.2)** gets queried, that's the failure case.

I've included my configuration files below.

How may I solve this problem?

### Zone Configuration (NS Records)

```
; project.example.com

@   NS   ns1
@   NS   ns2

sub   NS   ns1.sub

; Forward 3.0.10.in-addr.arpa rather than delegate it
; We can't delegate since we don't own 0.10.in-addr.arpa.
; That's why the line below is commented out.
; 203.240.10.in-addr.arpa.   NS   centos-s1.ipa

; Glue record
ns1.sub   A   10.0.3.2
```

### project.example.com Primary Nameserver Configuration

```
controls {};

acl "internal-hosts" { 10.0.0/22; 127/8; };
acl "external-hosts" { 10/8; 192.168/16; 172.16/12; };

view "internal-view" {
   match-clients { "internal-hosts"; };

   zone "project.example.com" {
      type master;
      file "db.project.example.com_internalView";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.0";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.1";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "2.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.2";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "3.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type forward;
      forwarders { 10.0.3.2; };
   };

   // Internal-only zone
   zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.172.31";
      forwarders { };
   };
};

view "external-view" {
   match-clients { "external-hosts"; };

   zone "project.example.com" {
      type master;
      file "db.project.example.com_externalView";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.0";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.1";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "2.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "db.10.0.2";
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "3.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type forward;
      forwarders { 10.0.3.2; };
   };
};
```

### project.example.com Secondary Nameserver Configuration

```
controls {};

acl "internal-hosts" { 10.0.0/22; 127/8; };
acl "external-hosts" { 10/8; 192.168/16; 172.16/12; };

masters "my-master" { 10.0.0.2; };

view "internal-view" {
   match-clients { "internal-hosts"; };

   zone "project.example.com" {
      type slave;
      file "bak.project.example.com_internalView";
      masters { my-master; };
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type slave;
      file "bak.10.0.0";
      masters { my-master; };
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type slave;
      file "bak.10.0.1";
      masters { my-master; };
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "2.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type slave;
      file "bak.10.0.2";
      masters { my-master; };
      forwarders { };
   };

   zone "3.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      type forward;
      forwarders { 10.0.3.2; };
   };

   // Internal-only zone
   zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa" {
      type slave;
      file "bak.172.31";
      masters { my-master; };
      forwarders { };
   };
};

view "external-view" {
   match-clients { "external-hosts"; };

   zone "project.example.com" {
      in-view "internal-view";
   };

   zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      in-view "internal-view";
   };

   zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      in-view "internal-view";
   };

   zone "2.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      in-view "internal-view";
   };

   zone "3.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
      // in-view "internal-view";
      type forward;
      forwarders { 10.0.3.2; };
   };
};
```